# hide function jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to display an error when function valid_name is not true and to hide  the error when the `valid_name` become true when blur;
Error is display in a div which is initially hidden.
The error appears but it doesn't disappear.

```
function valid_name() {
    if (($("#name").length > 5) && ($("#name").length < 20)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').on('blur', function() {
        if (!valid_name())
            $("#name_erors").text("invalid name").show();
        if (valid_name())
            $("#name_erors").hide();

    });
});
```

Comment: try: `$("#name").val().length`

Comment: @Sergio id is just another attribute. there can be as many as the bad UI developer puts in.

Comment: `$("#name").length > 5` is checking for more than 5 elements with the ID "name"

Comment: @Prasanth, multiple IDs is invalid HTML. KB9, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/18453687#18453687

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
$("#name").length
```

should

```
$("#name").val().length
```

Cause `$('#name').length` count the element found, but to count the character within you need to use

```
$("#name").val().length
```

So function should be

```
function valid_name() {
    if (($("#name").val().length > 5) && ($("#name").val().length < 20)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also do

```
function valid_name() {
    var value = $('#name').val(), len = value.length;
    return len > 5 && len < 40;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When selecting with jQuery, the returned object contains elements. In this case, there'll only be one, so the `length` will always be 1. You probably meant to select the length of the value.

That said, here's a [fully optimised Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) solution:

```
document.getElementById('name').onblur = function() {
    var notice = document.getElementById('name_errors');
    if( this.value.length > 5 && this.value.length < 20) notice.style.display = "none";
    else {
        notice.style.display = "block"; // or "inline", as applicable
        notice.innerHTML = "Invalid name length (must be between 6 and 19 characters)";
    }
};
```

This code should be placed either:

- anywhere after the `name` element
- in a script block with the `defer` attribute
- in a `window.onload` handler

Answer (score 1):

I think your function always returns `false`. Try,

```
function valid_name() {
        if (($("#name").val().length > 5) && ($("#name").val().length < 20)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#name').on('blur', function() {
                if (!valid_name())
                    $("#name_erors").text("invalid name").show();
                if (valid_name())
                    $("#name_erors").hide();

            });
        });
```

`.val()` gives the value of input field, and you should be checking value's length.

`$('#name').length` would return count of elements with id name, that is surely less than 5.

Answer (score 1):

You spelled the div id as "name_erors", which seems like a misspelling.  I would double check the spelling in the html first.